# Selecting a specific row followed by an order by?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this data

```
names
============
All
Brian
Carey
Heather
Robert
Zach
_Immediate
```

This is when they are selected `ORDER BY` name.  I would like to craft a statement so that the _Immediate appears at top like

```
names
============
_Immediate
All
Brian
Carey
Heather
Robert
Zach
```

If it matters/helps, _Immediate has the absolute lowest `ID` in the list.  How can I do this?  Is a `UNION` the only way?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the ORDER BY using a CASE expression:

```
ORDER BY CASE
             WHEN names = '_Immediate' THEN 0
             ELSE 1
         END
,        names
```

Comment: `name` on the last line should be `names`

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, I think the simplest method is:

```
order by (name = '_Immediate') desc, name
```

MySQL treats a boolean as an integer, with "1" for true and "0" for false.  The `desc` is so the "1" is before the "0".

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select * from tablename
order by case when names='_Immediate' then 0 else 1 end, names
```